# Adding border style to country which has geometry type polygon?

Tags: polygon, openlayers, style

I have a drop down list and when I select a country name and the map goes to this country, I want to add a specific border style to this country (polygon geometry).

Comment: To help, we'll need a little more information about your issue. To start, what software are you using?

Comment: When asking coding type question, relevant existing code should be included in the question. Please edit the question and add the code.

Comment: @DavidBartecchi As you can see from the tag, software is OpenLayers JS library.